# Visual Studio 2010 C++ debugger -- cannot see data

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Sometimes when using the data viewer in debug mode in Visual Studio 2010 (C++), I cannot see the data.  I can see the data of many other variables, but not the one shown below.  The element below is an array.  How do I get rid of the "(error)" messages and see the data?

[image]

Update: I wrote a member function called "view".  If I jump into the function call, the debugger works fine and I can see all the class variables.  So maybe this is an issue with the debugger following pointers.

[image]

Comment: You are using a Microsoft product. Have you considered; 1) Reading the product documentation? 2) Contacting Microsoft for support?   This is *not really* a C++ related question. Also; have you considered upgrading to VS2017? You might get better results and, in any case, VS2010's modern C++ standards compliance sucks dingoes kidneys.

Comment: @Jesper Please point us to the Microsoft Page entitled "When you see (error) in the debugger", that is part of the product documentation. Also, the OP tagged the question with Visual Studio and Debugging. Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: I did a few Google searches on "(error)" "Visual Studio 2010 Debugger" and found nothing.  What's the name of white box in the image above?
  I'm not even sure what to call it?  Data viewer box?  Debug window?
  Maybe I should have posted on the MSDN forum, but I didn't want to go through the hassle of setting up another account.  Hoping someone here has seen this before.  Might have something to do with viewing pointers.  The product that I am developing for only supports VS 2012 at the latest.

Comment: Just a note, you can use later versions of visual studio for projects that only support an earlier toolset. There is an option in the project properties that allows you to select Project->Properties->General->Platform Toolset So, I can use Visual Studio 2015 to develop for a project targeting 2010, for example.

Comment: @PentiumPro200 Forgive me if this is lame question, but are the variables you are mousing over in scope at the time you are trying to view them? you cannot see out of scope variables.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I used the Platform Toolset option 5 years ago to support VS 2005 inside VS2010.  When I upgrade my laptop next month, I'll try VS2017 first.  I checked out visual studio 2012 and 2015, but did not see any compelling reasons to upgrade since I only do C++ development and would not be able to use any later C++ features since my code has to compile with VS2012.

Comment: @Christopher, yes, this->tests is a member variable so it's always in scope.

Comment: Sorry man, I'm at a loss on this one. Hope others can answer.

Comment: @Christopher, no worries.  I'll give VS2017 a try sometime next month and see if that solves my issue.  Fortunately, this does not happen very often.  I figured maybe there was some setting that I needed to enable.

Comment: When this happens have you ensured that `this` is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Is your object "test" one of standard STL class (vector, set, etc..)?

If yes, usually you should get also size in debugger tooltip - and this looks like corrupted autoexp.dat file.

If you did some modification in autoexp.dat, then try to revert it back and check if this helps.

Comment: It's not an STL class, but a proprietary vendor-supported array.  The debugger works fine with it 80+% of the time.

Comment: ...and what is type of the objects stored inside? "(error)" is shown for the objects stored in the array.

Comment: It's storing a struct that I defined.